# Google Fonts CSS customization

Tags: html, css, fonts, google-fonts

I am using the Google Fonts CDN to use Montserrat in my project.

Applying CSS using the CDN is not yeilding the same results as it does on the font locally installed on my computer.

Here's the result using the CDN:
[image]

Here's the result using locally installed font:
[image]

You can notice the font is bolder on the locally installed font. I want to achieve the same results with the CDN as I did with the locally installed font.

Here's my code:

```css
body{
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
.medium-25{
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 500;
}
.regular-50{
    font-size: 50px;
}
.bold-italic-72{
    font-size: 72px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <p class="regular-50">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.</p>
    <p class="bold-italic-72">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>
    <p class="medium-25">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem eaque eveniet      fugiat
        maiores quod sapiente vel, voluptatum. Delectus est fugiat fugit illo, quibusdam tempora          voluptatem. Atque
        doloribus, enim et illum libero reprehenderit saepe ut vero.
        <br>
        <br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab aperiam deserunt dolorum exercitationem fuga
        fugiat incidunt laboriosam mollitia nihil nisi officia possimus rem repellendus repudiandae rerum sapiente
        voluptatibus, voluptatum. Cupiditate!</p>

</div>
```

Comment: Show how you are embedding the Google font. Did you include all the font weights you are using?

Comment: <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the looks of it you have selected a different font in the CDN, its possible there are multiple versions of a font like `regular` `medium` `bold` listed in a CND font. You'd have to look at the specific font page to see the different thicknesses.

try:

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/cssfamily=Montserrat:400,600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

notice the 400,600 these are your available thicknesses of the font

```css
body{
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
.regular-50{
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

Comment: You're right, I didn't select all the font weights in "customize" option before copying the <link>